# Testing for IsSubset-relation over multiple sets

Tags: c#, .net, performance, set

On the traversal of a graph I need to test whether an arc allows access to additional nodes that cannot be reached via arcs already travelled. So actually I want to test if the set of successors of the arc in question is a subset of the combined successors of the arcs already visited.

Here's some (inoptimal) code to illustrate the desired operation:

```
    public static bool ReachesAdditionalSuccs(
                    ISet<int>   additionalSuccCandidates,
                    ISet<int>[] succsAlreadyReachable)
    {
        ISet<int> curCombinedSuccsReachable = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (ISet<int> set in succsAlreadyReachable)
            curCombinedSuccsReachable.UnionWith(set);
        return (!additionalSuccCandidates.IsSubsetOf(curCombinedSuccsReachable));
    }
```

As I need to perform this operation in a process of expanding and searching a time-dynamic game tree, I cannot pre-build the combined sets of successors due to memory restrictions. Neither is marking the nodes as visited an option. I only can build the direct set of successors up front to speed up something.

I now wonder what is the fastest way to do that. In the code above I temporarily build a combined set in new Hashset-object. That's very time consuming and certainly not the smartest way. A diffrent approach that came to my mind is cycling through all nodes and manually test it against all part-sets using Hashsets. But that might also not be the best way...

Last thing I thought up was using SortedSets, as these should be combined easily (in O(n), like in a merge sort) and the isSubset-operation also has O(n)-complexity. Is there a smart way to achieve this without coding it oneself, so maybe even build-in in the Framwork? Or are there even any faster approaches?

Answer (score 1):

I think the optimum you can do for Sets is filtering numbers one by one but only until you have found one number that is not contained in any other set and stop right there. Expressed with Linq that would be:

```
public static bool ReachesAdditionalSuccs(
                    ISet<int> additionalSuccCandidates,
                    ISet<int>[] succsAlreadyReachable)
{
    return additionalSuccCandidates.Where(x => !succsAlreadyReachable.Any(set => set.Contains(x)))
                                   .Any();
}
```

Overall effort for the worst case (all numbers already contained in a set) would be `O(mn)` - assuming set lookup time is O(1) - where `m` is the number of numbers in `additionalSuccCandidates` and `n` is the number of sets in `succsAlreadyReachable`.

One further optimization would be using `SortedSets` - you can use the minimum and maximum to filter out the sets that you don't have to check in the first place:

```
public static bool ReachesAdditionalSuccs(
                    SortedSet<int> additionalSuccCandidates,
                    SortedSet<int>[] succsAlreadyReachable)
{

    var remainingSets = succsAlreadyReachable.Where(set => (set.Min <= additionalSuccCandidates.Min
                                                         && set.Max >= additionalSuccCandidates.Min)
                                                         || (set.Min <= additionalSuccCandidates.Max
                                                         && set.Max >= additionalSuccCandidates.Max))
                                             .ToList();

    return additionalSuccCandidates.Where(x => !remainingSets.Any(set => set.Contains(x)))
                                   .Any();
}
```

Comment: Hi @BrokenGlass, thanks for your ideas! I think I'll stick to your first approach using HashSets, I believe it's the clearest and hopefully for arbitrary input the fastest way to do it. The proposed optmiziation in the second approach would make the Contains-operation O(log n) and I don't think this will be outweighted by the possible gain for the set-elimination, but I might give it a try if everything else runs smoothly. - BTW: The filter for overlap-testing might be easier with `!(set.Max < additionalSuccCandidates.Min || set.Min > additionalSuccCandidates.Max)` and saves one comparison.